# How to save facebook account to ACAccountStore from facebookSDK

Tags: ios, facebook, acaccount, acaccountstore, facebook-sdk-3.1

I want to save the facebook account to `ACAccountStore` in iOS,

1. I will get `accessTocken` from facebookSDK but how to obtain tocken and secret
2. How to save it to `ACAccountStore`

Thanks in Advance.

------ Edit--------

I have an application that uses facebook to login and after with login information need to share photos that he selected.
My use cases are,

1. If account already in settings app then I can use it for login and share.
2. User using safari or webview for login then how I can proceed for sharing.

   a. facebook SDK says If the user need to use OS integrated share controller then, `login method used to authenticate the user must be native iOS 6.0 authentication.`.

   b. If I need to share option that provided by facebook SDK uses facebook App I don't want this option because I want to avoid App switching as much as possible.

How to solve this..

Comment: What's the motivation for saving the access token separately?

Comment: Need to save the facebook account information to settings App then only I can use social framework to share with that account...

Comment: If you're using the Facebook SDK, it automatically saves the Session information for you. Why not use the APIs provided by the SDK to share rather than using the social framework?

Comment: If I need to share with facebook SDK I need to install the facebook App over there, app switching is required.

Comment: and I tried to present OS integrated Dialog and I got error like this.. `Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=7 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 7.)" com.facebook.sdk:DialogReasonKey=com.facebook.sdk:DialogNotSupported`

Comment: I need more context on what you're trying to do in order to help. Code would be very helpful. There are multiple different types of dialogs you can use in order to share (with FB app installed or not), you can also get publish permissions directly, and share without any facebook dialogs.

Comment: I edited with more details. and method that I used for presenting OSIntegratedShareDialog is, `+ (BOOL)presentOSIntegratedShareDialogModallyFrom:(UIViewController*)viewController
                                          session:(FBSession*)session
                                      initialText:(NSString*)initialText
                                           images:(NSArray*)images
                                             urls:(NSArray*)urls
                                          handler:(FBOSIntegratedShareDialogHandler)handler;`

Comment: If you want to use the iOS integrated share sheet, then you have to get the login credentials from iOS, there's no way to work around it.

Comment: Yea then facebook SDK is not useful, If I have only login and sharing.

Comment: Well, a significant amount of users do not have iOS integration turned on, so if you ONLY use iOS integrated sharing/login, then you're ignoring a lot of potential users.

Comment: k. So you are saying its better to avoid login with social networks?.. Actualy login with social networks will helps to avoid form filling right?

Comment: No, I'm saying you should use the Facebook SDK for iOS, which handles login via iOS, the Facebook app, or web dialog, and also offers different types of share dialogs (and you can do checks on which one to show based on what's available).

Comment: k. If I use facebook SDK and  facebook App is not installed on that device then I need to force the user to do what Social framework provide right there is no difference in that  right?. If they allow to share through safari or webview that will be great..

Comment: You do not need to force Social framework, if the FB app is not installed, the SDK will fall back to using the Webview for login. There is also a Webview share dialog (under FBWebDialogs) that you can use.

Comment: which method? can you specify it?

Answer (score 0):

to do it you should have an accesstoken and secret,

```
if (self.accountStore == nil) {
    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
}

//make credentials to assign to ACAccount 
ACAccountCredential *credential = [[ACAccountCredential alloc] initWithOAuthToken:accesstoken tokenSecret:secret];
ACAccountType *acctType =[self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
ACAccount *newAccount = [[ACAccount alloc] initWithAccountType:acctType];

newAccount.credential = credential;

NSDictionary *options = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         "xXXXXXX", (NSString *)ACFacebookAppIdKey,
                         [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"basic_info"], (NSString *)ACFacebookPermissionsKey,
                         ACFacebookAudienceEveryone, (NSString *)ACFacebookAudienceKey,
                         nil];


[_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:acctType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if (granted == YES) {
        [self.accountStore saveAccount:newAccount withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

            if (success) {
                NSLog(@"the account was saved!");
            }
            else {
                if ([error code] == ACErrorPermissionDenied) {
                    NSLog(@"Got a ACErrorPermissionDenied, the account was not saved!");
                }
                NSLog(@"%@",error);
            }
        }];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@ ",error);
    }
}];
```

Comment: How I will obtain that secret and token?. I have accessToken.

Comment: NSString *accessToken = [[FBSession.activeSession accessTokenData] accessToken];

Comment: I said I have accessToken but how to separate token and secret?

Comment: In twitter from accessToken we need to separate token and secret. Same in facebook? and how?

Comment: sorry was in meeting. i think secret is not required here. try without it. @""

Comment: It shows Error `Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=6 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 6.)`